# ¿Como puedo hacer que un botones switch cambie el background de un TextView Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, activity, switch

Me gustaría saber como puedo cambiar el background-color de un TextView, a través de un botón switch.
Cabe aclarar que mis botones switch están en `MainActivy` y mis TextView están en otras Activities, a las cuales accedo así:

```
tvBoton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Horario);
        tvBoton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, central.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                 }
            });
```

No sé si influya en algo, pero mis botones switch tienen SharePreferences:

```
public static final String ex1 = "switch1";     
public static final String ex = "switch";
...
...
pol = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch18);
        sharpol = getSharedPreferences("pol", MODE_PRIVATE);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editorpol = sharpol.edit();
        pol.setChecked(sharpol.getBoolean(ex, false));
        pol.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean ispolChecked) {
                if (ispolChecked) {
                    editorpol.putBoolean(ex, true);
                    politica=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.polit);
                    politica.setText("No funciona");
                } else {
                    editorpol.putBoolean(ex, false);
                }
                editorpol.commit();
            }
        });
```

Como esta en el código anterior, intente dentro del ispolChecked, en la opción true, referenciar el TetView, y luego poner setText, pero este TextView, al estar dentro de otro layout no funciona.
También puse `setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)` varias veces, pero cambiándolo a los layouts respectivos, pero tampoco funciono.

Sinceramente, ya no se que hacer. Gracias por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tus botones switch están en `MainActivity` y tus`TextView` están en otras Activities, puedes controlar el fondo del `TextView` ya que estas guardando una preferencia para indicar el cambio.

Ve a la Activity en donde se encuentra el TextView que deseas cambiarle el background y obtén el valor que guardaste de la preferencia usando la llave "switch" con la cual se guardo el valor en la preferencia:

```
  SharedPreferences  sharpol = getSharedPreferences("pol", MODE_PRIVATE);
  Boolean valor  = sharpol.getBoolean("switch", false);

  if(valor){
     textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
  }else{
     textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
  }
```

Comment: Gracias, ya pude cambiarle el color al TextView, pero, cuando activo y/o desactivo el botón switch, el color no cambia, creo que es porque en la parte del `sharpol.getBoolean`, pide definir un valor, y al pasarle el valor false, la variable valor siempre va a elegir el color pasado en el else

Comment: Que valor tiene "ex" aquì "editorpol.putBoolean(ex, true);" que es donde cambias el valor.

Comment: Esto es lo que tengo: `public static final String ex1 = "switch1";
    public static final String ex = "switch";`

Comment: ok, entonces usa la llave "switch" para extraer el valor de la preferencia, de hecho modifique tu pregunta y mi respuesta.

Comment: Si me sirvió. Gracias, de verdad gracias, me ayudaste muchísimo  <3

Comment: Excelente Samuel, saludos.